# jQuery find elements that match criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got a tricky one where I want to add a `class` to *all the parent* `<tr>`'s of `<td>`'s which *have* either a `<span>` or a `<div>` element within them. So I have a table with markup as below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span></span>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I want the `<td>`'s that have either a `<span>` or `<div>` to have a *class* added to them by **jQuery**...

I can't seem to work out how to loop through all the `<td>`'s to check their descendant and then add the class to those that have either a `<span>` or `<div>` inside... Is this possible?

Thanks for any light you can shed on it! It's driving me mad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check with **[.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/)** if `tr` has `div` or `span` as a descendant:

```
$('table tr').has('div,span').addClass('someClass');
```

Check the **below snippet:**

```js
$('table tr').has('div,span').addClass('someClass');
```

```css
.someClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>
      <div>div</div>
    </td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
    <td>td 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>span</span>
    </td>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>
      <div>div</div>
    </td>
    <td>td 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
    <td>td 4</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Good stuff, never even knew this was a feature in jQuery.